# Response content type is not as expected

Tags: jmeter

When I call the API is postman than I am receiving the right response whose content-type is application/json, where as when I do the same api call in Jmeter the response content-type is text/html.

The response recieved in Jmeter is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/  
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
   -->
  <!-- Material -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>XXXXX</title>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-yi9s3pf1.js"></script>
  <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/msal-Yz2giFI8.js">
  <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/vendor-oOUBVzm4.js">
  <link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="/assets/mui-BPEiaP5i.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-QXuHfPLk.css">
</head>
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

Where as response received in Postman is:

{
"adEmailAddress": "test2@XXXX.com",
"displayName": "test2",
"employeeId": "XXXX",
"groups": [
"XXX_User"
]
}

tried adding content type to request header

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not getting the same response it means that you're not sending "the same" request.

Check pretty much everything:

- URL
- Request payload (if applicable)
- Request [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (especially [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type))

Also be aware that given you're able to run the request successfully in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/installation/proxy/) and run your request, JMeter will capture it and generate appropriate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/convert-postman-api-tests)

Comment: Thanks for the response.. You are right i had misspelled a letter in the url in JMeter